# The 'to' date field not updating

Tags: entities, datetime

Out of the box the date field can accept a 'from' and 'to' date parameters and the 'to' date field will auto update when the 'from' field changes. As work has progressed on my site the field no longer automatically updates. Any idea as to why this would happen?

Comment: Are you sure the field did update in the past? I never noticed such behavior...

Comment: I could have sworn it did.

Comment: Could you provide step by step instructions on how to reproduce this? I tried in simplytest.me with latest Drupal 7 and date module. But after saving a node and editing the first value again, nothing changed in the second value.

Answer (score 1):

I recreated the date field settings on a clean install of drupal. I installed/enabled views, ctools, and the date api. I enabled the date popup widget and created a dummy content type. The popup and textfield widgets for the date field do NOT auto update but the select list does. I guess this is how it is designed. Back to the drawing board on this one. the popup module could possibly be modified to allow auto updating.